# Checkbox answers won't save when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, checkbox

I'm clearly a beginner and am having the hardest time saving the checkbox answers to the page when submitted. Below is the code for the page (sorry it's long, checkboxes start at 314). My gut feeling is that I'm missing a string of code but I can't figure out for the life of me what it could be. Thanks in advance, I owe everyone on this forum the most gratitude!

Edit: I've included the FieldCheckBox code in my revised question.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bool, string } from 'prop-types';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { FormattedMessage, injectIntl, intlShape } from '../../util/reactIntl';
import { Field, Form as FinalForm, FormSpy } from 'react-final-form';
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { ensureCurrentUser } from '../../util/data';
import config from '../../config';
import arrayMutators from 'final-form-arrays';
import { propTypes } from '../../util/types';
import * as validators from '../../util/validators';
import { isUploadImageOverLimitError } from '../../util/errors';
import { Form, Avatar, Button, ImageFromFile, IconSpinner, FieldTextInput, FieldCheckbox } from '../../components';

import css from './ProfileSettingsForm.module.css';

const ACCEPT_IMAGES = 'image/*';
const UPLOAD_CHANGE_DELAY = 2000; // Show spinner so that browser has time to load img srcset



class ProfileSettingsFormComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.uploadDelayTimeoutId = null;
    this.state = { uploadDelay: false };
    this.submittedValues = {};
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Upload delay is additional time window where Avatar is added to the DOM,
    // but not yet visible (time to load image URL from srcset)
    if (prevProps.uploadInProgress && !this.props.uploadInProgress) {
      this.setState({ uploadDelay: true });
      this.uploadDelayTimeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ uploadDelay: false });
      }, UPLOAD_CHANGE_DELAY);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.clearTimeout(this.uploadDelayTimeoutId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FinalForm
        {...this.props}
        render={fieldRenderProps => {
          const {
            className,
            currentUser,
            handleSubmit,
            intl,
            invalid,
            onImageUpload,
            pristine,
            profileImage,
            rootClassName,
            updateInProgress,
            updateProfileError,
            uploadImageError,
            uploadInProgress,
            form,
            values,
          } = fieldRenderProps;





          const user = ensureCurrentUser(currentUser);

          // First name
          const firstNameLabel = intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'ProfileSettingsForm.firstNameLabel',
          });
          const firstNamePlaceholder = intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'ProfileSettingsForm.firstNamePlaceholder',
          });
          const firstNameRequiredMessage = intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'ProfileSettingsForm.firstNameRequired',
          });
          const firstNameRequired = validators.required(firstNameRequiredMessage);

          // Last name
          const lastNameLabel = intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'ProfileSettingsForm.lastNameLabel',
          });
          const lastNamePlaceholder = intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'ProfileSettingsForm.lastNamePlaceholder',
          });
          const lastNameRequiredMessage = intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'ProfileSettingsForm.lastNameRequired',
          });
          const lastNameRequired = validators.required(lastNameRequiredMessage);

          // Bio
          const bioLabel = intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'ProfileSettingsForm.bioLabel',
          });
          const bioPlaceholder = intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'ProfileSettingsForm.bioPlaceholder',
          });

          //Amenities


          const uploadingOverlay =
            uploadInProgress || this.state.uploadDelay ? (
              <div className={css.uploadingImageOverlay}>
                <IconSpinner />
              </div>
            ) : null;

          const hasUploadError = !!uploadImageError && !uploadInProgress;
          const errorClasses = classNames({ [css.avatarUploadError]: hasUploadError });
          const transientUserProfileImage = profileImage.uploadedImage || user.profileImage;
          const transientUser = { ...user, profileImage: transientUserProfileImage };

          // Ensure that file exists if imageFromFile is used
          const fileExists = !!profileImage.file;
          const fileUploadInProgress = uploadInProgress && fileExists;
          const delayAfterUpload = profileImage.imageId && this.state.uploadDelay;
          const imageFromFile =
            fileExists && (fileUploadInProgress || delayAfterUpload) ? (
              <ImageFromFile
                id={profileImage.id}
                className={errorClasses}
                rootClassName={css.uploadingImage}
                aspectRatioClassName={css.squareAspectRatio}
                file={profileImage.file}
              >
                {uploadingOverlay}
              </ImageFromFile>
            ) : null;

          // Avatar is rendered in hidden during the upload delay
          // Upload delay smoothes image change process:
          // responsive img has time to load srcset stuff before it is shown to user.
          const avatarClasses = classNames(errorClasses, css.avatar, {
            [css.avatarInvisible]: this.state.uploadDelay,
          });
          const avatarComponent =
            !fileUploadInProgress && profileImage.imageId ? (
              <Avatar
                className={avatarClasses}
                renderSizes="(max-width: 767px) 96px, 240px"
                user={transientUser}
                disableProfileLink
              />
            ) : null;

          const chooseAvatarLabel =
            profileImage.imageId || fileUploadInProgress ? (
              <div className={css.avatarContainer}>
                {imageFromFile}
                {avatarComponent}
                <div className={css.changeAvatar}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.changeAvatar" />
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className={css.avatarPlaceholder}>
                <div className={css.avatarPlaceholderText}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.addYourProfilePicture" />
                </div>
                <div className={css.avatarPlaceholderTextMobile}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.addYourProfilePictureMobile" />
                </div>
              </div>
            );

          const submitError = updateProfileError ? (
            <div className={css.error}>
              <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.updateProfileFailed" />
            </div>
          ) : null;

          const classes = classNames(rootClassName || css.root, className);
          const submitInProgress = updateInProgress;
          const submittedOnce = Object.keys(this.submittedValues).length > 0;
          const pristineSinceLastSubmit = submittedOnce && isEqual(values, this.submittedValues);
          const submitDisabled =
            invalid || pristine || pristineSinceLastSubmit || uploadInProgress || submitInProgress;


          return (
            <Form
              className={classes}
              onSubmit={e => {
                this.submittedValues = values;
                handleSubmit(e);
              }}
            >
              <div className={css.sectionContainer}>
                <h3 className={css.sectionTitle}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.yourProfilePicture" />
                </h3>
                <Field
                  accept={ACCEPT_IMAGES}
                  id="profileImage"
                  name="profileImage"
                  label={chooseAvatarLabel}
                  type="file"
                  form={null}
                  uploadImageError={uploadImageError}
                  disabled={uploadInProgress}
                >
                  {fieldProps => {
                    const { accept, id, input, label, disabled, uploadImageError } = fieldProps;
                    const { name, type } = input;
                    const onChange = e => {
                      const file = e.target.files[0];
                      form.change(`profileImage`, file);
                      form.blur(`profileImage`);
                      if (file != null) {
                        const tempId = `${file.name}_${Date.now()}`;
                        onImageUpload({ id: tempId, file });
                      }
                    };

                    let error = null;

                    if (isUploadImageOverLimitError(uploadImageError)) {
                      error = (
                        <div className={css.error}>
                          <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.imageUploadFailedFileTooLarge" />
                        </div>
                      );
                    } else if (uploadImageError) {
                      error = (
                        <div className={css.error}>
                          <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.imageUploadFailed" />
                        </div>
                      );
                    }

                    return (
                      <div className={css.uploadAvatarWrapper}>
                        <label className={css.label} htmlFor={id}>
                          {label}
                        </label>
                        <input
                          accept={accept}
                          id={id}
                          name={name}
                          className={css.uploadAvatarInput}
                          disabled={disabled}
                          onChange={onChange}
                          type={type}
                        />
                        {error}
                      </div>
                    );
                  }}
                </Field>
                <div className={css.tip}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.tip" />
                </div>
                <div className={css.fileInfo}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.fileInfo" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={css.sectionContainer}>
                <h3 className={css.sectionTitle}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.yourName" />
                </h3>
                <div className={css.nameContainer}>
                  <FieldTextInput
                    className={css.firstName}
                    type="text"
                    id="firstName"
                    name="firstName"
                    label={firstNameLabel}
                    placeholder={firstNamePlaceholder}
                    validate={firstNameRequired}
                  />
                  <FieldTextInput
                    className={css.lastName}
                    type="text"
                    id="lastName"
                    name="lastName"
                    label={lastNameLabel}
                    placeholder={lastNamePlaceholder}
                    validate={lastNameRequired}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={classNames(css.sectionContainer, css.bioSection)}>
                <h3 className={css.sectionTitle}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.bioHeading" />
                </h3>
                <FieldTextInput
                  type="textarea"
                  id="bio"
                  name="bio"
                  label={bioLabel}
                  placeholder={bioPlaceholder}
                />
                <p className={css.bioInfo}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.bioInfo" />
                </p>
                </div>

                <div className={classNames(css.sectionContainer, css.amenitiesSection)}>
                  <h3 className={css.sectionTitle}>
                    <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.amenities" />
                  </h3>


<div class="checkbox container">
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id1" name="checkbox-group" label="Gas Oven" value="option1" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id2" name="checkbox-group" label="Electric Oven" value="option2" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id3" name="checkbox-group" label="Induction Oven" value="option3" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id4" name="checkbox-group" label="Convection Oven" value="option4" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id5" name="checkbox-group" label="Broiler" value="option5" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id6" name="checkbox-group" label="Double Oven" value="option6" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id7" name="checkbox-group" label="Pizza Oven" value="option7" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id8" name="checkbox-group" label="Cast Iron" value="option8" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id9" name="checkbox-group" label="Pressure Cooker" value="option9" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id10" name="checkbox-group" label="Stand Mixer" value="option10" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id11" name="checkbox-group" label="Meat Grinder" value="option11" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id12" name="checkbox-group" label="Kitchen Scale" value="option12" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id13" name="checkbox-group" label="Blender" value="option13" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id14" name="checkbox-group" label="Food Processor" value="option14" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id15" name="checkbox-group" label="Deep Fryer" value="option15" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id16" name="checkbox-group" label="Charcoal Grill" value="option16" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id17" name="checkbox-group" label="Gas Grill" value="option17" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id18" name="checkbox-group" label="Electric or Manual Smoker" value="option18" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id19" name="checkbox-group" label="Griddle" value="option19" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id20" name="checkbox-group" label="Pasta Roller" value="option20" />
<FieldCheckbox id="checkbox-id21" name="checkbox-group" label="Rice Cooker" value="option21" />
</div>
</div>

              {submitError}
              <Button
                className={css.submitButton}
                type="submit"
                inProgress={submitInProgress}
                disabled={submitDisabled}
                ready={pristineSinceLastSubmit}
              >
                <FormattedMessage id="ProfileSettingsForm.saveChanges" />
              </Button>
            </Form>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

ProfileSettingsFormComponent.defaultProps = {
  rootClassName: null,
  className: null,
  uploadImageError: null,
  updateProfileError: null,
  updateProfileReady: false,
};

ProfileSettingsFormComponent.propTypes = {
  rootClassName: string,
  className: string,

  uploadImageError: propTypes.error,
  uploadInProgress: bool.isRequired,
  updateInProgress: bool.isRequired,
  updateProfileError: propTypes.error,
  updateProfileReady: bool,

  // from injectIntl
  intl: intlShape.isRequired,
};

const ProfileSettingsForm = compose(injectIntl)(ProfileSettingsFormComponent);

ProfileSettingsForm.displayName = 'ProfileSettingsForm';





export default ProfileSettingsForm;
```

```html
import React from 'react';
import { node, string } from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { Field } from 'react-final-form';

import css from './FieldCheckbox.module.css';

const IconCheckbox = props => {
  const { className, checkedClassName, boxClassName } = props;
  return (
    <svg className={className} width="14" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
        <g transform="translate(2 2)">
          <path
            className={checkedClassName || css.checked}
            d="M9.9992985 1.5048549l-.0194517 6.9993137C9.977549 9.3309651 9.3066522 10 8.4798526 10H1.5001008c-.8284271 0-1.5-.6715729-1.5-1.5l-.000121-7c0-.8284271.6715728-1.5 1.5-1.5h.000121l6.9993246.0006862c.8284272.000067 1.4999458.671694 1.499879 1.5001211a1.5002208 1.5002208 0 0 1-.0000059.0040476z"
          />
          <path
            className={boxClassName || css.box}
            strokeWidth="2"
            d="M10.9992947 1.507634l-.0194518 6.9993137C10.9760133 9.8849417 9.8578519 11 8.4798526 11H1.5001008c-1.3807119 0-2.5-1.1192881-2.5-2.4999827L-1.0000202 1.5c0-1.3807119 1.119288-2.5 2.500098-2.5l6.9994284.0006862c1.3807118.0001115 2.4999096 1.11949 2.4997981 2.5002019-.0000018.003373-.0000018.003373-.0000096.0067458z"
          />
        </g>
        <path
          d="M5.636621 10.7824771L3.3573694 8.6447948c-.4764924-.4739011-.4764924-1.2418639 0-1.7181952.4777142-.473901 1.251098-.473901 1.7288122 0l1.260291 1.1254782 2.8256927-4.5462307c.3934117-.5431636 1.1545778-.6695372 1.7055985-.278265.5473554.3912721.6731983 1.150729.2797866 1.6951077l-3.6650524 5.709111c-.2199195.306213-.5803433.5067097-.9920816.5067097-.3225487 0-.6328797-.1263736-.8637952-.3560334z"
          fill="#FFF"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

IconCheckbox.defaultProps = { className: null, checkedClassName: null, boxClassName: null };

IconCheckbox.propTypes = { className: string, checkedClassName: string, boxClassName: string };

const FieldCheckboxComponent = props => {
  const {
    rootClassName,
    className,
    svgClassName,
    textClassName,
    id,
    label,
    useSuccessColor,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  const classes = classNames(rootClassName || css.root, className);

  // This is a workaround for a bug in Firefox & React Final Form.
  // https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/134
  const handleOnChange = (input, event) => {
    const { onBlur, onChange } = input;
    onChange(event);
    onBlur(event);
  };

  const successColorVariantMaybe = useSuccessColor
    ? {
        checkedClassName: css.checkedSuccess,
        boxClassName: css.boxSuccess,
      }
    : {};

  return (
    <span className={classes}>
      <Field type="checkbox" {...rest}>
        {props => {
          const input = props.input;
          return (
            <input
              id={id}
              className={css.input}
              {...input}
              onChange={event => handleOnChange(input, event)}
            />
          );
        }}
      </Field>
      <label htmlFor={id} className={css.label}>
        <span className={css.checkboxWrapper}>
          <IconCheckbox className={svgClassName} {...successColorVariantMaybe} />
        </span>
        <span className={classNames(css.text, textClassName || css.textRoot)}>{label}</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  );
};

FieldCheckboxComponent.defaultProps = {
  className: null,
  rootClassName: null,
  svgClassName: null,
  textClassName: null,
  label: null,
};

FieldCheckboxComponent.propTypes = {
  className: string,
  rootClassName: string,
  svgClassName: string,
  textClassName: string,

  // Id is needed to connect the label with input.
  id: string.isRequired,
  label: node,

  // Name groups several checkboxes to an array of selected values
  name: string.isRequired,

  // Checkbox needs a value that is passed forward when user checks the checkbox
  value: string.isRequired,
};

export default FieldCheckboxComponent;
```

Comment: You should use an `onChange` attribute on yoru checkbox and save the value to the state. Kind of like this: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-checkbox/

Comment: A) You don't need to write every single checkbox like that. B) You may need to "handle" what needs to happen when a checkbox is clicked (ie, selected/checked or de-selected/unchecked). Please try something like this: `<div class="checkbox container>{chkArray.map((lbl, idx) => (<FieldCheckbox id={"checkbox-id" + (idx+1).toString()} name="checkbox-group" label={lbl}/>))}</div>` where `chkArray` is like this: `const chkArray = ["Gas Oven", "Electric Oven", ......, "Pasta Roller", "Rice Cooker"];`. The `......` should be replaced with the actual labels. Also, please share FieldCheckbox component.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I included the FieldCheckBox component in my question now.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be an exact solution for this particular `FieldCheckbox` component, this may provide a simple reference for how multiple check-boxes may be used.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const MyCheckbox = ({id, name, value, label, clickHandler, idx, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <div key={idx}>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id={id}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onClick={clickHandler}
      />
      <label for={id}>{label}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

class Thingy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cbStatus: {}
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { cbLabels } = this.props;
    const { cbStatus } = this.state;
    const checkedItems = [];
    Object.entries(cbStatus).forEach(([k ,v]) => {
      if (v) checkedItems.push(cbLabels[k-1])
    });
    return (
      <div>
        checked Items: {checkedItems.join(', ')} <br/> <br/>
        {
          cbLabels && Array.isArray(cbLabels) &&
          cbLabels.length > 0 && cbLabels.map((lbl, idx) => (
            <MyCheckbox
              id={`checkbox-id${idx+1}`}
              name={'checkbox-group'}
              value={`option${idx+1}`}
              label={lbl}
              clickHandler={() => this.setState(prev => ({
                ...prev,
                cbStatus: {
                  ...prev.cbStatus,
                  [idx+1]: !(prev.cbStatus[idx+1])
                }
              }))}
            />
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  };
}

const itemsList = ['Gas Oven', 'Electric Oven', 'Other Items', 'Pasta Roller', 'Rice Cooker'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h3> CheckBox Demo </h3>
    <Thingy cbLabels={itemsList} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation**

- `cbStatus` is a state variable (object) used to track which checkboxes are checked
- Within `MyCheckbox` component, the `onClick` event is handled
- The `name`, `value` and `id` props for the checkbox are all made similar to the OP's question

This above snippet may be helpful when one needs to necessarily handle the onClick even of a checkbox. For scenarios such as form-submission where no dynamic changes will be needed on the UI (except for the checkbox getting tick/clear-ed), handling `onClick` may not be required.